# Как изменить текст вью в кастомном макете бокового меню?

Tags: android, textview, android-navigation-drawer

Сделал кастомный макет для меню в **Navigation Drawer**. Внутри этого макета есть **TextView** для которых мне нужно периодически менять текст, например счетчик. Но по каким то причинам у меня не получается этого сделать.

Макет с меню размещается внутри **NavigationView**.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_task_list">

        <include layout="@layout/navigation_drawer_menu"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Так инициализирую вью элементы внутри `onCreate`.

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_drawer_menu, null);
mCounter = view.findViewById(R.id.menu_counter);
```

Сейчас из `mCounter` можно получить текущий текст, но никак не получается установить новый. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

**ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНО**

Обновляю счетчик меню внутри следующего кода, который находится в `onCreate`.

```
DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        initTaskCounters();
        }
    };
drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();
```

И еще заметил странность, может поможет разобраться.

Если внутри `onCreate` инициализировать **TextView** со счетчиком, а потом сразу присвоить ему другой текст и показать это в логе. То изменения присутствуют. Но когда открывается боковое меню, там все равно остаются видны по умолчанию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Макеты и вью элементы находящиеся внутри **NavigationView**, правильно инициализировать без использования **LayoutInflater**.

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
mCounter = navigationView.findViewById(R.id.menu_counter);
```